# remove last character from string

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to create a new dataframe column (b) removing the last character from (a).
column a is a string with different lengths so i am trying the following code -

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
df.select(substring('a', 1, length('a') -1 ) ).show()
```

I get a TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

it seems to be due to using multiple functions but i cant understand why as these work on their own -

if i hardcode the column length this will work

```
df.select(substring('a', 1, 10 ) ).show()
```

or if i use length on it's own it works

```
df.select(length('a') ).show()
```

why can i not use multiple functions ?
is there an easier method of removing the last character from all rows in a column ?

Answer (score 7):

Using `substr`

```
df.select(col('a').substr(lit(0), length(col('a')) - 1))
```

or using `regexp_extract`:

```
df.select(regexp_extract(col('a'), '(.*).$', 1))
```

Function `substring` does not work as the parameters `pos` and `len` needs to be integers, not columns
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=substring#pyspark.sql.functions.substring

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct.you just need to use `len` function.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([('abcde',)],['dummy'])

from pyspark.sql.functions import substring

df.select('dummy',substring('dummy', 1, len('dummy') -1).alias('substr_dummy')).show()

#+-----+------------+
#|dummy|substr_dummy|
#+-----+------------+
#|abcde|        abcd|
#+-----+------------+
```

Comment: This only work for your example where `len('dummy')` is just len of the python string 'dummy' which happens to be the same length as `'abcde'` in the dataframe.